# Usage of M2Crypto package

Tags: python, labview, m2crypto

I want to encrypt the communication between a LabView and a Python code. I did some preliminary research and I found the [AES library](http://www.soslabview.com.ar/en/node/4) for LabView. The M2Crypto module supports AES.

My question is if the AES is the best solution for TCP communication. Can anybody provide a simple example in python?

Comment: If you are going to communicate over the network an alternative could be to use SSH and tunnel the data through it. It would probably perform much quicker than anything implemented in python.

Comment: The sad things that we already have a software and now we just want to implement the secure communication. If we want to use SSH we have to rework completely the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at the SOS AES library, and it seems that it's adding some data to the encrypted data, they use when de-encrypting.
You might want to try out my library available at [LAVA](http://lavag.org/topic/14889-cr-encryption/page__hl__encryption__fromsearch__1) and [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/tcplomp/labviewencryption).